# An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: Invalid template property or properties [WebAppGroup, WebAppLaunchConfig]

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have the following configuration for WebAppLaunchConfig and WebAppGroup, not sure why I am getting that error.

```
escription: >
    High availability web app
Parameters:

    EnvironmentName:
        Description: An environment name that will be prefixed to resource names
        Type: String
Resources:
  LBSecGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow http to our load balancer
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-VPCID"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  WebServerSecGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow http to our hosts and SSH from local only
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-VPCID"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 0
        ToPort: 65535
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

WebAppLaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          # Install docker
          apt-get update
          apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
          curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
          add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y docker-ce
          mkdir docker-test
          cd docker-test
          wget  https://udagram-dev-u.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/index.html.zip 
          apt-get install unzip
          unzip index.html.zip
          echo "FROM ubuntu:latest" >> Dockerfile
          echo "RUN apt-get update" >> Dockerfile
          echo "RUN apt-get install -y nodejs" >> Dockerfile
          echo "RUN apt-get install -y npm" >> Dockerfile
          echo "RUN npm install -g http-server" >> Dockerfile
          echo "WORKDIR /usr/apps/test-docker/" >> Dockerfile
          echo "COPY index.html /usr/apps/test-docker/" >> Dockerfile
          echo 'CMD ["http-server", "-s"]' >> Dockerfile
          docker build -t "test:test-docker" .
          usermod -aG docker ubuntu
          docker run -d -p 8080:8080 "test:test-docker"
      ImageId: ami-005bdb005fb00e791
      SecurityGroups:
      - Ref: WebServerSecGroup
      InstanceType: t3.medium
      BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: "/dev/sdk"
        Ebs:
          VolumeSize: '10'

WebAppGroup:
      Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
      Properties:
        VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - Fn::ImportValue: 
            !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-PRIV-NETS"
        LaunchConfigurationName:
          Ref: WebAppLaunchConfig
        MinSize: '4'
        MaxSize: '6'
        TargetGroupARNs:
        - Ref: WebAppTargetGroup
```

Comment: Can you edit it like a YAML file?

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is incorrect for `WebAppLaunchConfig` and `WebAppGroup`. Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see these errors inline while authoring templates:

```
E1001 Top level template section escription is not valid
E1001 Top level template section WebAppLaunchConfig is not valid
E1001 Top level template section WebAppGroup is not valid
E1012 Ref WebAppTargetGroup not found as a resource or parameter
```

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Apart from **indentation issues** (see other answer), your template is **missing definition** of `WebAppTargetGroup` resource.

Thus unless you are showing only part of your template, even after correcting the indention it will not deploy. You need to have `WebAppTargetGroup` defined or remove it from your AutoScaling Group.